# Azure Mobile Service : Insert to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, arrays, azure, middleware, azure-mobile-services

I'm building a food ordering system in my app (html 5 sdk). When creating item, an item can have multiple toppings (Extra Cheese, extra chicken etc).

So this is what I wanna do

1. Insert item into the `Items` Table (I can simply do it)
2. Get the Array of toppings sent from app and insert it into `Toppings` Table (NOt sure how to send the array of toppings. Each topping will have a name and price) Can I add them as an attribute to items insert service request and send??

**Problem**

I can insert an item without problem, but I have no idea how to get the array list of toppings and insert it into Topping tables.

Can I send array of objects as an attribute in the Azure mobile services service request?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to have a custom insert script on your Items table so that it parses an array and inserts each item of the array into a Toppings table (including item id, if you need that).  For example:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    var toppings = item.Toppings;
    item.Toppings = null;
    request.execute({ success: function() {
        var toppingsTable = tables.getTable('Toppings');
        var count = 0;
        toppings.forEach(function(topping, index) {
            topping.itemId = item.id;
            toppingsTable.insert(topping, {
                success: function() {
                    count++;
                    if (toppings.length === count) {
                        request.respond();
                    }
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.warn('Error while inserting toppings objects', err);
                    count++;
                    if (toppings.length === count) {
                        request.respond();
                    }
            });
        }});
    }
```

Comment: oh wow thanks it worked :) btw I found a mistake. `count` variable should be initialized at `0` not `toppings.length`